# two cisco routers, using json, paramiko

Tags: python, json, networking, paramiko

I am trying to connect to two cisco routers by using a JSON file, in paramiko python.
Please explain what is wrong with these two files.
Start of code

```
import json
from sys import stdout
from paramiko import *
json_file_object = open('test.json','r+')
List_of_Devices = json.load(json_file_object)
cmd_to_exec = 'show running-config'
for device in List_of_Devices['test']:
output_file_name = str(device['name'] + '.txt')
ssh_object = SSHClient()
ssh_object.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy)
ssh_object.load_host_keys()
ssh_object.connect(device['SSH_IP,SSH_PORT,SSH_USER,SSH_PASSWORD'])
ssh_object.exec_command(cmd_to_exec)
output = stdout.readlines()
file_object = open(output_file_name,'w')
for x in output:
    file_object.write(x)
```

Start of JSON code: is the JSON code format right?

```
[
    {
        "HOST_NAME" : "R1",
        "SSH_IP" : "192.168.1.2",
        "SSH_PORT" : 22,
        "SSH_USER" : "wahid",
        "SSH_PASSWORD" : "wahid"
    },
    {
        "HOST_NAME" : "R2",
        "SSH_IP" : "192.168.1.3",
        "SSH_PORT" : 22,
        "SSH_USER" : "wahid",
        "SSH_PASSWORD" : "wahid"
    }
]
```

End of JSON code:

Comment: You need to provide what happens when you run this code, and what you expect to happen. From inspecting the code, I imagine you’re having trouble with the `ssh_object.connect()` as the parameters you provide are not what you think. You are not correctly accessing multiple values of a dict. You likely should have `device[“SSH_IP”], device[“SSH_PORT”], …` hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. i changed it to this -> ssh_object.connect(device['SSH_IP'],device['SSH_PORT'],device['SSH_USER'],device['SSH_PASSWORD']), I changed it, and worked. it executes up to line. ouput = stdout.readlines(). > it says not readable. what this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion in the comments, I wanted to provide an answer to help anyone that may find this question in future.

The first problem I noted was the incorrect passing of parameters to the `connect()` method. You needed to use it like so. `ssh_object.connect(device["SSH_IP"], device["SSH_PORT"], device["SSH_USER"], device["SSH_PASSWORD"])`.

The second problem you indicated had to do with the need for retrieving `STDOUT`. You attempted to use the `sys.stdout` library. However `paramiko` has a way of retrieving the output from the client. Here's the link for that documentation: [Paramiko Client](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html). Below is the adjusted code. You will still need to determine what to do with the output.

```
import json
from sys import stdout
from paramiko import *
json_file_object = open('test.json','r+')
List_of_Devices = json.load(json_file_object)
cmd_to_exec = 'show running-config'
for device in List_of_Devices['test']:
    output_file_name = str(device['name'] + '.txt')
    ssh_object = SSHClient()
    ssh_object.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy)
    ssh_object.load_host_keys()
    # Fixed the below line to pass the various parameters you needed.
    ssh_object.connect(device["SSH_IP"], device["SSH_PORT"], device["SSH_USER"], device["SSH_PASSWORD"])
    # Below changed to obtain the stdout into the std_out variable
    std_in, std_out, std_err = ssh_object.exec_command(cmd_to_exec)
    # It is possible you will want to be sure std_out is what you expect uncomment the print below to view it.
    # print(std_out)
    # You should always use a context to wrap a file operation so you don't have to remember to close the file
    with open(output_file_name, "w") as file_object:
        file_object.write(std_out)
```